# Difference between V, T and E in Java

Tags: java, generics

I use `javap` often.

So when I see JDK classes across, I understood that probably:

- `T` means Type;
- `E` means Enumertion;
- Meaning of `V` is unclear for me.

Please shed some light on this question?

Maybe I am wrong. But I see several JDK classes belongs to package `java.util.function.*` , `java.util.concurrent.*` has this `V`, `T`, `E` in place of `class` type, `return` type.

Comment: `V` stands for *value*. These are only *type variables*, placeholders for the actual types, and you can call them with any name you like. The common convention is use single uppercase letters like `T`, `R`, but compiler be happy with `Cat`, `zzzzzz` and event names of existing JDK classes like `Integer` (which is discauraged).

Comment: I think `V` is value, -`return` value for the method.

Comment: `V` can be observed in the `Map` interface, and its nested interface `Map.Entry`. To refer to return value `R` is frequently used, but there's no strong rule for that.

Comment: E means element, I think. I have seen it in some other feed in stakoverflow

Comment: Also I see, `R U A N`. `A` is Array. `N` is Number. `R` is reduce in stream probably. Remaining? - `U` I do know.

Comment: `R` - refers to Runtime. But not mandatorily to mentioned as R as others say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a feature called generics which is used to develop classes such that its functionality can be used with any type of objects. The letter you see like `T`, `E` or `V` are just place holders. For example `List<E>`. This is substituted with actual class when start using the list like below.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Java uses this approach to check type safety so that a `String` object cannot be added to an `Integer` list.

```
numbers.add(1); //Good
numbers.add("Harry"); //Compilation error
```

Here are some useful resources.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Answer (score 2):

In **Java 5** [*Generic types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) were introduced in the language. In a nutshell generics - is a mechanism of type safety, they are meant to make the code more robust. Generics allow writing clean and highly reusable code without performing `instanceof` checks and type-casting (to be precise type-casts are still there, they would be added by the compiler under the hood, and they are safe).

`V`, `T`, `E`, etc. are so-called [*type variables*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4). These are only placeholders, not the actual types, i.e. it's a way to tell the compiler that you expect a particular type at runtime and you can refer to this type using type variable.

In your code, you can call type variables with **any** name you like. The common convention is to use single uppercase letters like `T`, `R`, but compiler be happy with `Cat` as a type variable, and even with a name of existing JDK classes and interfaces like `Integer` (which is highly  discouraged, but your code would compile).

```
public class MyClass<T> {}       // OK
public class MyClass<CAT> {}     // OK
public class MyClass<Integer> {} // OK, note `Integer` is just a placeholder and has the the same meaning as `T` or `A`
public class MyClass<super> {}   // will NOT compile, keywords and restricted identifiers (like `record` which isn't a keyword) can't be used as generic type parameters
```

Regarding type variables that you can encounter in the JDK, there's no common policy that has been listed anywhere. Sometimes there's some informal intuition behind these names, sometimes probably **not** (e.g. when you see `T`, `U`, `V` defined together as generic variables you can clearly observe that it's an order of letters in the English alphabet, `T` - stands for type, and `U`, `V` are simply some other types distinct from `T` and each other).

Speaking of cases when probably there's some meaning:

- `E` - in `Collection<E>` most likely means *element*, and in `Enum<E>` - stands for *enum*.
- `R` in `Function<T,R>` stands for result, or return type of the function.
- `K` and `V` in `Map<K,V>` and `Map.Entry<K,V>` stand for *key* and *value*.
- `A` in the `Collector<T,A,R>` interface is meant to represent *accumulation type* (type of the *mutable container* which *collector* uses internally).